# Why does my App.Config have this strange Assembly Redirect?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I do not understand the `0.0.0.0-` prefix on the "old version"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means:

**Redirect all requests for versions `0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1` (i.e. any ver<=`4.0.2.1`) to version `4.0.2.1`**

Referring to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element):

> *oldVersion* :    Required attribute.
>
> Specifies the version of the assembly that was originally requested. The format of an assembly version number is major.minor.build.revision. Valid values for each part of this version number are 0 to 65535.
>
> ***You can also specify a range of versions in the following format:***
>
> ***n.n.n.n - n.n.n.n***

So in your example, we have a range of:

```
0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1
```

or any version less than or equal to `4.0.2.1`.

Comment: Awesome thanks @spender! If you have experience with these redirects, maybe you can help me figure out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48715745/where-does-the-nuget-get-project-all-add-bindingredirect-get-its-version-numb

Comment: ...took a peek, spent a moment on it, got nowhere, bedtime. Good luck.