# Where does the Nuget Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect get its version numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, web-config, app-config

I'm trying to synchronize all of the DLL versions in my solution with many projects. I noted that my app.config contains several assembly binding redirects like so:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.2.1" newVersion="4.0.2.1" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

However, as best I can tell via the NuGet package manager, there are no packages that need consolidation and all projects point to version 4.4.1 of that assembly

I tried folowing the advice of [this blog post](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2014/11/27/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-nuget-assembly-redirects.html). I deleted all of the binding redirects and attempted to regenerate via:

> Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect

According to the [NuGet Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/powershell-reference#Add-BindingRedirect) `Add-BindingRedirect` should check the projects output path. I am assuming this means the bin folder.

But after cleaning and rebuilding `Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect` still produces the same redirects in my `app.config`.

Where does the NuGet `Get-Project -All | Add-BindingRedirect` get its version numbers?

And where might these incorrect NuGet Package Versions be coming from?

Comment: Doesn't version number come from the DLL which was referenced from given NuGet package? If you installed A.nupkg which contains A.dll of version 1.2.3.4 then if assembly binding redirected is added it would be 1.2.3.4.

Comment: I have netstandard projects that use [System.ComponentModel.Annotations, 4.5.0] and a [NET Framework 4.7.2] UnitTest project that uses 4.2.1 from the same assembly. Even if the netstandard package is installed for the unit test project - which is necessary to test the component - the binding redirects are refreshed using the NET framework versions not the ones included in packages.config. So it seems that the nuget packages are not taken into consideration when the binding redirects are automatically updated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the `Add-BindingRedirect` adds `<assemblyBinding>` tags to the configuration file even after clearing all files in the output folder (seems like the documentation is not accurate in this regard !!).

Apparently `Add-BindingRedirect` scans all of the referenced DLLs and all of their dependencies, and if it finds any conflicts throughout the dependency tree it generates the required `assemblyBinding`s.

#### Example

If you have a csproj called "MyProject" which references two DLLs (from two different Nuget Packages)

1. `SomePackage.dll`
2. `AnotherPackage.dll`

And both DLLs reference `BasePackage.dll`, but each one of them references a different version of the `BasePackage.dll`, for example:

1. `SomePackage.dll` references `BasePackage.dll` version 1.
2. `AnotherPackage.dll` reference `BasePackage.dll` version 2.

When you run `Add-BindingRedirect` command, it will scan all the DLLs referenced by "MyProject" and spot this conflict in `BasePackage` references, then adds something like this to your configuration file.

```xml
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="BasePackage" publicKeyToken="50bd4fe62226aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this Article

Starting with Visual Studio 2013, new desktop apps that target the .NET Framework 4.5.1 use automatic binding redirection. This means that if two components reference different versions of the same strong-named assembly, the runtime automatically adds a binding redirection to the newer version of the assembly in the output app configuration (app.config) file. This redirection overrides the assembly unification that might otherwise take place. The source app.config file is not modified. For example, let's say that your app directly references an out-of-band .NET Framework component but uses a third-party library that targets an older version of the same component. When you compile the app, the output app configuration file is modified to contain a binding redirection to the newer version of the component. If you create a web app, you receive a build warning regarding the binding conflict, which in turn, gives you the option to add the necessary binding redirect to the source web configuration file.

Source: [Click Here to Read More about Binding Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions)

Comment: The question is where does NuGet Add-BindingRedirect get its information. Sometimes, NuGet will add the binding redirects that Visual Studio complains about, but it won't, for example, if a project is unloaded. One of my referenced projects uses and old version of System.Collections.Immutable, and if that project is unloaded in Visual Studio, NuGet's Add-BindingRedirect will not add the redirect, even though Visual Studio's build warns that it should be added. If I load the load that project, then NuGet is able to detect the missing redirect. So where is NuGet getting it's dependency info?